# script to add superscript in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split

hello everyone I should add the character " ' " at the end of each word contained in a string, where the final letter is accented. for instance: Niccòlò Niccòlò -> Niccòlò' Niccòlò'

```
let stringa= "nicolò à";
let apice ="\'";
let stringa2 = stringa.split(' ');
let stringa3 =stringa2.join(' ');


for(let i=0; i<stringa.length; i++){
    if(i == stringa.length-1){
        if(stringa3[i]== "ò" || stringa[i]== "è" || stringa[i]== "à" || stringa[i]== "ì" || stringa[i]== "é" || stringa[i]== "ù" || stringa[i]== "ú" || stringa[i]== "í" || stringa[i]== "á" || stringa[i]== "ó"){
            stringa3 = stringa3 + apice;
        }
    }
    
    console.log(stringa3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pattern checking for those chars at the end of a "word" with a character class for the chars and a lookahead to assert a whitspace boundary to the right.

```
[òèàìéùúíáó](?!\S)
```

In the replacement use the full match using `$&` followed by `'`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7pjFo9/1) for the matches.

```js
let stringa = "nicolò à test Niccòlò Niccòlò";
const pattern = /[òèàìéùúíáó](?!\S)/g;
console.log(stringa.replace(pattern, "$&'"));
```

Comment: maybe add the `i` (case incensitive) attribute in your RegExp so it include capital accentuated letters ?
@Lorenzo don't forget to accept the answer if it is what you were looking for ! :)